# Error response from jQuery ajax to asp.net WebService, but there's no error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I have an ajax query which calls a `WebService`. It works and does its thing, and returns nothing at all (it's a void). No errors in the application while debugging. But the error event for jquery .ajax keeps firing. textStatus and errorThrown are undefined. XMLHttpRequest has no indication of an error state.

Why does this query think it is getting an error response?

Also odd: if I put breakpoints in the WebMethod, the error gets thrown at the client BEFORE the method finishes. It does not seem to wait for it to finish, it just goes right to the error event. I expect this has something to do with the problem here...

```
$.ajax({
        url: baseUrl() + "/webservices/usersetting.asmx/SetSetting",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        data: $.toJSON(ajaxData),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown + " data: " + ajaxData.id);
        }
    });
```

When debugging in the error event:

```
XMLHttpRequest
abort: function (){w&&Function.prototype.call.call(g,w);L("abort")}
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
onreadystatechange: function (){}
readyState: 4
response: ""
responseText: ""
responseType: ""
responseXML: null
status: 0
statusText: ""
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload
withCredentials: false
__proto__: XMLHttpRequest
```

Here is the method. I tried it with void return, and "true". Tried responseformat Xml and Json. No difference.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true),
ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public string SetSetting(List<UserSettingData> data)
{
    UserSettingManager setMgr = new UserSettingManager(Global.UserSession.UserID);
    foreach (UserSettingData item in data)
    {
        setMgr.SetSetting(item.name, item.value);
    }

    return (jsonString(true));
}
```

Comment: Is this a cross domain request?

Comment: nope, all running on my dev machine right now.

Comment: I would recommend installing fiddler 2 and seeing if you can get some additional information.  The status value in your XMLHttpRequest should be 200 if it was successful.

Comment: Installed fiddler2. New to that, seems a bit dicey in my environment, get lots of "access forbidden" errors loading resources. But did get it to work after reloading a few times. The response does indeed show "HTTP/200: 1" as the only thing under response codes for the web service. So I tried uncommenting the error handler, and lo and behold it's working now?? I haven't changed much else so I really don't know how to explain this, maybe just had visual studio loaded for too long...

Comment: Are you using FireBug. If yes, does the Net -> XHR -> XML have any errors. I'm guess you're getting a XML parser exception

Comment: Thanks @Narmatha.. i got this resolved per my last comment (that is, it resolved itself, inexplicably), I should close it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after Visual Studio restarted. No idea why but done and done.